# Gradle giving ClassNotFoundException while building Grails project

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to use the gradle-grails-plugin to build an existing (small) Grails project.  Should this work?  What is the relationship between the dependencies in `build.gradle` and the ones specified in `buildConfig.groovy`?

In any event, I have two projects, so the topmost `build.gradle` file is in the parent directory and looks like:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.2.0.RC1"
   }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
   gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

and then the build.gradle in the Grails project looks like:

```
apply plugin: "grails"

repositories {
   grails.central() //creates a maven repo for the Grails Central repository (Core libraries and plugins)
}

grails {
   grailsVersion = '2.4.4'
   groovyVersion = '2.3.9'
   springLoadedVersion '1.2.0.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
   bootstrap "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.55.3" 
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:3.0.1' 

   compile 'org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.2'
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.8'

   runtime 'org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.1.1'
   runtime 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.3.8'
   runtime 'org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.0'
}
```

However, when I run `./gradlew war`, I get back:

```
Caused by: java.long.ClassNotFoundException: grails.artefact.Service
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?  There are practically no references to that via Google, it seems to be a Grails 3.x class? Also, I am using Java 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Class `grails.artefact.Service` is indeed accessible from v3.0 of grails framework - as can be seen [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/api/grails/artefact/Service.html).

With the following statement `grailsVersion = '2.4.4'` v2.4.4 is specified to be used and it all looks ok. What spoils the build is the following `dependencies` entry:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:3.0.1'
```

In this package there is a class `asset/pipeline/grails/AssetProcessorService` that imports the mentioned `grails.artefact.Service` which isn't loaded at runtime (probably because of v2.4.4 used).

Unfortunately I can't suggest any solution apart from the trivial like excluding this dependency. I am not a grails developer nor have I set the environment up.

Hopes that helps somehow.

Comment: @JoeG, was it helpful?